# Overlapping -Werror and -Wno-error for same flag

Tags: c++, build

We have a complex build system that can be used on both windows and linux. On windows, compiler already give an error for a non void function with no return statement. We want to make the builder raise an error on Linux if there is a non-void function with no return statement. In order to do this, We have add "-Werror=return-type" to the project flags, which means this flag will be work on all projects and components. Then some 3rd party components raised an error because of this. We want to exclude that flag from 3rd party components and add "-wno-error=return-type" to the component flags of the 3rd party components, which means this flag will be work only on the related component.

Now the problem is for that 3rd party components there are both -Werror=return-type and -Wno-error=return-type flags. These are collided and still raise an error for a non void function with no return statement. Is there any other way to do this. How can I handle this overlapping situation?

Thanks for advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It might be useful someone try to figure out how to Werror and Wno-error works.

the last given flag has the priority. I mean If you give that options in order, like $somecommand -Werror=something -Wno-error=something  compiler gets the latest flag active and will not raise an error.
In my case the error caused by the order of the component flags. I have re-arrenged the order and write -Werror before the component flags and resolved.